# The Chofetz Chaim on a meis mitzvah

Tags: sources-mekorot, mitzvah, chofetz-chaim

In [*Ginzei Hakodesh*](http://www.israelbookshoppublications.com/store/pc/Ginzei-Hakodesh-p716.htm) on page 333 it says the following:

*"'The wise man buys **mitzvos** - particularly when we are speaking of **'meis mitzvah,'** one that is neglected as if it were dead. It is well known that the Chofetz Chaim zt"l wrote that one who becomes involved in mitzvos that are considered 'meis' will have a greater reward than any other  person."*

Does anyone know where the Chofetz Chaim says this?

Answer (score 1):

He says it in Sefer Shmiras HaLashon (Shaar HaTorah ch. 10) [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=9ZtBAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA1-PA71&lpg=RA1-PA71&dq=%D7%97%D7%A4%D7%A5%20%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%9E%D7%AA%20%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%94&source=bl&ots=kNj9McWegM&sig=h2WcVn-VPCoeTikwEwuFiiKxlFk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAGoVChMI9PHMnf-UxwIVxM-ACh07rASS#v=onepage&q=%D7%97%D7%A4%D7%A5%20%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%9E%D7%AA%20%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%94&f=false) and [here](http://chafetzchayim.org/index.php/component/content/article/23-sefer-shemirat-halashon-read-online):

> ידוע מש"כ בס"ח דמצוה שאין לה דורשין היא כמת מצוה

He goes on to discuss the general importance of meis mitzvah, but I dont see him writing explicitly that it carries greater reward.

Comment: Related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/48907/learning-laws-of-aveilut-when-your-parents-are-alive/49027#49027 (The context where the Sefer Chassidim says it).

Comment: @mevaqesh: Firstly, thank you very much for the quick response! Secondly, can you tell the exact words of where he says [it](http://chafetzchayim.org/index.php/component/content/article/23-sefer-shemirat-halashon-read-online)?

Comment: BTW, the Sefer Chassidim (http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=38149&st=&pgnum=60&hilite=) says that it is a great reward. (CC: @ChiddusheiTorah).

Comment: @Yishai: What's the exact wording of the Sefer Chasidim?

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah, ותקבל שכר גדול כנגד כולם